# How to create dynamic multilevel menu in Angular material

Tags: angular, menu, nested, angular-material

I have a problem. I need to create a dynamic multilevel menu using angular material, the data source looks like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "Frontend",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "HTML"
            },
            {
                "name": "Angular"
            },
            {
                "name": "CSS"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Backend",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Node"
            },
            {
                "name": "PHP",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Cake PHP"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The data structure can grow up to any depth, therefore is dynamic. How can adapt this to create a dynamic multilevel angular material menu?. The documentation just take static examples

Comment: share the code you already atempted?

Comment: You'll need to use *ngFor loop on the children.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I am working on it if I have success I'll share the code for now I'm get blocked because the documentation is not enough

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for the answer. If yes, then I have created a plugin for Angular which creates a Multilevel menu.

Here is a [NPM Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-multilevel-menu) and [Github Link](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu), the documentation is very sweet and simple.

Just in case, if you wanna see more examples, I have a  [demo](https://multilevel-menu-demo.web.app/) for you and this is the [Github Repo](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu-demo) of the demo.

If something doesn't work for you, and you still wanna use this plugin, then [create an issue here](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu/issues) I'll help you out.

P.S. it works in IE11 as well.

Thanks